# single quotes around server variable classic asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, escaping, single-quotes

I have the following link being created dynamically in a legacy .asp application.

```
<a href='javascript:OpenIncompleteProposal(<%=iProposalID%>, <%=Server.UrlEncode(Session("Security_UserFullName"))%>)'><%=sClientName%></a>
```

When this renders it renders with no quotes around either parameter, i want the second parameter surrounded by single quotes.  i know it should be easy but escaping the strings and wrapping the globalsession variable is causing me some trouble.

Comment: Is that the actual code in your .asp page

Comment: How does this render? `<a href="javascript:OpenIncompleteProposal(<%=iProposalID%>, '<%=Server.UrlEncode(Session("Security_UserFullName"))%>')"><%=sClientName%></a>`

Comment: Why use the `javascript:` moniker just attach your event handlers?? Its poorly supported deprecated approach. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/134957/692942